# How to make Angular and Rails interact? Unknown format error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ngresource

I have ngResource directive included in my **first** project in order to be able to interact with RESTful API.

Then I setup my factory like this:

```
angular.module('app').factory('User', [
  '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/user_login/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
      update: { method: 'PUT' }
    });
  }
]);
```

In my controller I try to save User i.e to send POST request.

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', [
  '$scope', 'User', function($scope, User) {
    return User.save();
  }
]);
```

My **second** project's controller look like the following. I'm trying to reference create action.

```
class UserSessionsController < UserApplicationController
  respond_to :js, only: :create

  def create
    if @counterparty
      session[:counterparty_id] = @counterparty.id
      @counterparty.update(signed_in: true)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email or password'
    end

    respond_with(@counterparty, layout: false)
  end
end
```

As a result I'm getting ActionController::UnknownFormat.

[image]

```
Started POST "/user_login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-18 16:04:58 +0200
Started POST "/user_login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-18 16:04:58 +0200
Processing by UserSessionsController#create as HTML
Processing by UserSessionsController#create as HTML
  Counterparty Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `counterparties`.* FROM `counterparties`  WHERE `counterparties`.`email` IS NULL AND `counterparties`.`password` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Counterparty Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `counterparties`.* FROM `counterparties`  WHERE `counterparties`.`email` IS NULL AND `counterparties`.`password` IS NULL LIMIT 1
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 1ms
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 1ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you include full Rails log for that request?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change
    `respond_to :js, only: :create`
to
    `respond_to :json, only: :create`

user factory is doing a request in json format, although the controller should respond to js (json included) that didn't work for op, so it's necessary to set respond_to json explicitly

Comment: Can you explain how the answer fixes the trouble?

Comment: sure, user factory is doing a request in json format, although the controller should respond to js (json included) that didn't work for op, so it's necessary to set respond_to json explicitly

Comment: Great. Can you edit the answer to reflect the explaination?

Comment: What If I have to respond to both formats depending on request? I need js to exist in my project as well.

Comment: You can add multiple respond_to in your controller action, as Pitabas suggested

Answer (score 1):

Replace the create function with following function

```
    def create
      respond_to do |format|
       if @counterparty
         session[:counterparty_id] = @counterparty.id
         @counterparty.update(signed_in: true)
         format.json  { render :json => @counterparty.to_json ,status: :ok}
       else
         format.json  { render :json => 'Invalid email or password',status: :unprocessable_entity}
       end
      end
   end
```